# W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0 on camera.open() call

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I'm writing a camera app and whenever I call camera.open() the app crashes and then I get this error:

`W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0`

Here is how I'm opening the camera:

```
public void getCameraInstance(){
    mCamera = null;

    try 
    {
        mCamera = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)

    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you are reading this please note that this is for the original camera API and no longer applies the the latest version of the camera api (camera2).

You should use the camera2 api from this point onwards as it has greater functionality and also has a better image processing pipeline.

NOTE ONLY VALID UP TO excluding API 21 (Lolipop) i.e. does not apply for Lolipop 
and above.

Comment: Which device do you use? Does it have a working camera? Do you request camera permission in the manifest? Have you tried `open(0)` and `open (1)`?

Comment: I'm using a moto g, although I've tried with an emulated camera and am getting the same problem

Comment: I see that you start by setting `camera` to **null**. If your `camera` object is not null, you are expected to call `camera.release()` before you can open a new one.

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that when I get home

Comment: where is the conclusion OP ? 2 people went to help you, you got 4 upvotes... Where is your part of the job ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use the following method

```
android.hardware.Camera.open(int cameraId)
```

You should pass cameraId, If you want the front camera Id you can use the following method

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {

    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            cameraFront = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
```

1. If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.
2. You must call release() when you are done using the camera, otherwise it will remain locked and be unavailable to other applications.
3. Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time
   for a particular hardware camera.

Answer (score 33):

You manualy uploaded your application to phone. That is why camera permission is not approved. You have to open settings->applications (or something like that) and manualy approve this permission.

Comment: I mean open settings on your phone, and approve camera permission for your application))

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is exactly what caused the problem here. I had to manually approve camera permissions in the application settings.

Comment: This is the best answer! It's the only one explaining what's happening and providing the most meaningful solution.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue when running an app from Android Studio

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue!

Comment: Hi small point here. Yes if you do not have permission to access the camera you will get an error. That being said, this advice only applies to API levels higher than 21, in which case you should be using the camera2 api, which uses different syntax (and has different errors)

Answer (score 12):

In Android 6, make sure you request permission for the camera. Camera access is considered one of the ['dangerous permissions'](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups).

Comment: Or set target API level <= 22, if you don't need anything higher.

Comment: That isn't a good solution. You're going to have to support API 22 eventually.

Answer (score 10):

make sure your app has permission for camera, e.g

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes that was the first thing that I did

Comment: This is a very likely cause for the error, for the casual stackoverflow searcher.

Answer (score 3):

i got the answer for this:
this is for marshmallow permission issue:
add this in your project:

step 1:

```
 private static final int REQUEST_GET_ACCOUNT = 112;
 private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
```

step2:

```
 int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
```

step3:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), GET_ACCOUNTS);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{GET_ACCOUNTS, CAMERA}, REQUEST_GET_ACCOUNT);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (locationAccepted && cameraAccepted)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access location data and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(CaptureActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: You are awesome.. I have been stuck with this issue for days, and this worked. Thanks

Comment: @Sri just for reference you should post another question since this question isn't valid for anything above API 20 this also apply to you vels

Comment: Further reading: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

try to close the camera after you finish your work 
in my case i use  mScannerView.stopCamera() because i use it to scan code QR.

Comment: In my case, there is a bug when I call startCamera() twice from "onResume()". The second is failed and causing this problem. Even after I call stopCamera() it does not work. So, make sure we do not call startCamera() more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In my case your code work ,after adding this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: You don't need `uses-feature`. That just filters your app in the store.