# An error occurred while connecting to camera Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to make a simple barcode scanner with zxing and I have used the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    //Do anything with result here :D
    Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    //Resume scanning
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

}

but I keep on getting the following error

> An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0

Here is the log

```
    08-23 13:07:09.412 24318-24318/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample V/ViewRootImpl: Contents drawing finished : com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample.MainActivity
08-23 13:07:09.414 24318-24318/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d9ac315 time:103259036
08-23 13:07:25.832 24318-24318/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
08-23 13:07:25.869 24318-24318/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
08-23 13:07:25.876 24318-24318/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample I/AudioManagerEx: AudioManagerEx created
08-23 13:07:25.941 24318-24890/com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
```

here is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gnirt69.qrcodesannerexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do I modify the above code to get rid of this error?
Thanks

Comment: share the permission you used in manifest also show your logcat error

Comment: share your code from manifest file!

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: I still get the same error ` W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0 `

Comment: are you trying on emulator or real device with camera

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261769/w-camerabase-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0-on-camera-open-c

Comment: I am using a real device