# The camera is in use by another app

Tags: android, camera, opentok

I am developing a webRTC app using opentok. The app was working fine. I converted the app to library and launching the library activity by adding it to another project. The app is connecting to server but camera not opening. I am getting camera error as follows

```
E/opentok-videocapturer: The camera is in use by another app
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:518)
                                                                     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:360)
                                                                     at com.opentok.android.DefaultVideoCapturer.init(DefaultVideoCapturer.java:110)
                                                                     at com.opentok.android.BaseVideoCapturer.initTrap(BaseVideoCapturer.java:223)
```

Comment: After struggling for days with this issue I found it was a Camera permissioning problem in Marshmallow and up. Please refer to the [answer by 'vels' on the stack overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261769/w-camerabase-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0-on-camera-open-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (camera != null)
            {
                camera.release();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```